# Scrapyd web interface missing items list option issue

Tags: scrapyd

I'm learning how to deploy scrapy project to scrapyd server.
There is an issue on my scrapyd server web interface -- missing the 'items' option. As the following two pictures shown:
It should look like this one

[scrapyd web interface with items option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12hTP.png)

But what I got is this one - missing the 'items' option

[scrapyd web interface missing items option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsCPu.png)

Am I missing some scrapyd configuration? Or may be there is something wrong with my installation?

Thank's very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what am I missing. I need to config items_dir in .scrapyd.conf file.
More details of configuring scrapyd can check the [docs](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html)